# How to instantiate an interface object?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an `abstract` class and several implementations.

Based on the implementation class, I'd like to execute a method and instantiate the implementation class itself with `new` constructor.

Of course the following won't work as the class is `Abstract`, and I cannot change this fact. But how could I pass the "logic" how to create each implementation object to the method `prepareList()`? Especially regarding design decisions.

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    int id;
    String name;
    int age;
    //lots of fields
}

class FirstClass extends AbstractClass {

}

class SecondClass extends AbstractClass {

}


class MyService {
    void execute(Data data) {
        List<FirstClass> list = prepareList(data, FirstClass.class);
        //process list
    }

    List<AbstractClass> prepareList(Data data, Class<? extends AbstractClass> clazz) {
        List<AbstractClass> collection = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Some value in data.getList()) {
            AbstractClass obj = new AbstractClass(); //does of course not work with abstract class
            obj.setId();
            obj.setName();
            obj.setAge();
            collection.add(obj);
        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: A factory is a common scheme.

Comment: Maybe with reflection `clazz.getConstructor().newInstance()`

Comment: @bmargulies could you give an example of the factory pattern to be applied here?

Comment: Is the concrete type determined by the `Data` object? It seems that generics may solve this problem, depending on the output of `data.getList()`.

Comment: How do you determine the concrete type?

Comment: @jaco0646 the `Data` object does not matter in any way, that's my I just called it data.

Comment: @plalx the moment I call the method I'm aware of the concrete type I want to use, that's why I passed `FirstClass.class` in `prepareList` in my example.

Comment: @membersound There are many ways to do this. You can create an instance of the passed class dynamically using reflection with `AbstractClass obj = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance()`. If you do not want to rely on reflection you will need a factory which may be as simple as a lambda expression. E.g. `prepareList(data, () -> new FirstClass())` ... `prepareList` uses the second argument as a factory function to create the correct instance.

Comment: Lambda expression looks promising.

Comment: There is no need for getConstructor().  [clazz.newInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract class Fruit { String name; int weight; }
class Apple extends Fruit {}
class Orange extends Fruit {}

class FruitFactory() {
    public Fruit create(Data data) {
        if ("apple" == data.getFruitName()) return new Apple();
        else if ("orange" == data.getFruitName()) return new Orange();
        else throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

class FruitService {

   private FruitFactory factory = new FruitFactory();

   void execute(Data data) {          
       List<Fruit> list = prepareList(data);
   }

   List<Fruit> prepareList(Data data) {
       List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
       for (Some value : data) {
          Fruit fruit = factory.create(data);
          // set fields
          fruits.add(fruit);
       }
       return fruits;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay I have a suggestion why don't you do like

```
public class AbstractClass {
    int id;
    String name;
    int age;
    //lots of fields


}

class FirstClass extends AbstractClass{

}

class SecondClass extends AbstractClass{

}

class Data{

}

class Myservice{
    void execute(Data data) {
        List<FirstClass> list = prepareList(data, new FirstClass());//notice change
        //process list
    }

    List<AbstractClass> prepareList(Data data, AbstractClass abstractClassObj) {
        List<AbstractClass> collection = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Some value in data.getList()) {
          /*  AbstractClass obj = new AbstractClass();*/ //does of course not work with abstract class
            abstractClassObj.setId();
            abstractClassObj.setName();
            abstractClassObj.setAge();
            collection.add(obj);
        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

BY this your object creation and logic will also remain at different places. It will also be helpful if in future you have another class extending abstract class

or you can have some factory and pass factory object to your method or service class and get instance in the method you want.

Sorry In a hurry I missed the loop thing with factory try some thing like

```
public class AbstractClass {
    int id;
    String name;
    int age;
    //lots of fields

}

class FirstClass extends AbstractClass{

}

class SecondClass extends AbstractClass{

}

class Factory{
    public AbstractClass getInstance( Class<? extends AbstractClass> clazz){
        if(clazz.getSimpleName().equals(FirstClass.class.getSimpleName())){
            return new FirstClass();
        }else {
            return new SecondClass();
        }
    }
}

class Data{

}


class Myservice{

    private final Factory factory;
    public Myservice(Factory factory){
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    void execute(Data data) {
        List<FirstClass> list = prepareList(data, FirstClass.class);//notice change
        //process list
    }

    List<AbstractClass> prepareList(Data data,  Class<? extends AbstractClass> clazz) {
        List<AbstractClass> collection = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Some value in data.getList()) {
            AbstractClass obj = factory.getInstance(clazz);
            abstractClassObj.setId();
            abstractClassObj.setName();
            abstractClassObj.setAge();
            collection.add(obj);
        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

Obviously you can modify example as per needs you can use enum sort of things. This is just basic example

Comment: If you pass a blank object, it will be overridden within the `foreach` loop. This is of course not intended, but should create a new object during each loop.

Comment: @membersound okay then passing a factory object is better approach when I find time I will update answer with factory design

Comment: @membersound have a look I edited and added factory approach. Sorry I missed loop thing in a hurry